# OpenStreetMap coloring the map tiles by state, zip code polygons from C# VS 2013 WPF desktop application

Tags: openstreetmap, c#, tiles, wpf

[My question is likely to close on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107754/openstreetmap-coloring-the-map-tiles-by-state-zip-code-polygons-from-c-sharp-vs).

My aim is to create a map from C# VS2013 WPF desktop application (not web application) with OpenStreetMap on win7.

This a colored map with US states colorized differently.

This can be shown in the attachment below.

[image: an example]

I am new to WPF and handle the map tiles from XAML.

It seems to be very hard to find state or zip code borders from the map tiles and do coloring on them.

I have tried to add an image to the map to show colors but it cannot be aligned well with the adm areas/polygons. It was also stretched when zoom-in/out. I have tried to overlay one maptile on top of another one but there are always build errors. I have tried to search a similar  example code to find out how to implement the coloring for adm areas on map tiles, but I cannot find one.

The C# code in which I need to put an image (defined in "MyTileSource") on top of map tiles. I hope that the overlayed map tiles can be aligned well and zoomed/panned well. I got error:

> TileLayerCollection was not found in MapControl

But, actually, it has been defined.

This is only the first step. Currently, the "MyTileSource" is just a simple single-colored png. I still need to find out how to find state/county/zip-code borders in each map tile so that I can do coloring based on these administrative polygon areas.

```
 <map:Map >        
  <map:TileLayers>
        <map:Map.TileLayerCollection>
            <map:TileLayer
                    SourceName="OpenStreetMap"
                    TileSource="http://{c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    MaxZoomLevel="19"/>
            <map:TileLayer>
                <map:TileLayer.TileSource>
                    <map:MyTileSource/>
                </map:TileLayer.TileSource>
            </map:TileLayer>
        </map:Map.TileLayerCollection>
    </map:TileLayers>
</map:Map>
```

Comment: Why work from finished tiles? Why not just use the source vector format?

Comment: @BradHards, I am new to map tiles. Could you please show me an example how to use source vector to do coloring on the polygons with administrative borders ? thanks

Comment: You are expected to at least make an attempt. Right now it looks like you are asking us to do your work for you - [gis.se] doesn't work like that. There are a lot of options and tool sets (e.g. http://www.osmsharp.com/)

Comment: @BradHards, Actually, I have been working on this for one month. I have tried to add an image to the map to show colors but it cannot be aligned well with the adm areas/polygons. It was also stretched when zoom-in/out. I have tried to overlay one maptile on top of another one but there are always build errors. I have tried to search a similar  example code to find out how to implement the coloring for adm areas on map tiles, but I cannot find one,

Comment: @BradHards, I checked osmsharp.com one month ago and I did not find a similar example of how to do coloring on maptiles by adm. polygon/areas.

Comment: I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour] to learn how this site works.  The key things are to ask only one clear question, and if it involves code, then you need to include a code snippet that shows what you have tried and where you are stuck.  "I have tried to add an image to the map to show colors but it cannot be aligned well with the adm areas/polygons" sounds more focussed so perhaps revise your question to try and solve that first.

Comment: cross-posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107754/openstreetmap-coloring-the-map-tiles-by-state-zip-code-polygons-from-c-sharp-vs and http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?pid=564681